# IoC container auto-wiring with multiple instances of a type (in .NET)

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I have an app which uses dependency injection but does not currently use any IoC container. I currently have something like the following in my app setup code:

```
ISimpleDependency ez = new SimpleDependency();
ISomeOtherDependency otherDep = new SomeOtherDependency();

FooConfig fooConfigA = Settings.Default.FooConfigA;
FooConfig fooConfigB = Settings.Default.FooConfigB;

IFoo fooA = new Foo(fooConfigA, ez);
IFoo fooB = new Foo(fooConfigB, ez);

Bar bar = new Bar(fooA, otherDep);
Baz baz = new Baz(fooB, ez, otherDep);
Qux qux = new Qux(fooA, fooB); //params IFoo[] constructor to which we want to pass every Foo
```

In order to reduce the complexity of my app setup code and to improve maintainability, I would like to introduce an IoC container. Is there any way I can use an IoC container here to auto-wire everything without tightly coupling the Foo/Bar/Baz/Qux classes to the choice of IoC container implementation?

Comment: I believe that the [Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649564.aspx) IoC container _would be compatible_ with your sample code, but I can't imagine an IoC container that could _simplify_ it.

Comment: That's not to say that it wouldn't simplify your project as a whole if you have other dependencies that have less specific needs than the types you included in your question.

Comment: Please read [this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/) and [this](https://simpleinjector.org/blog/2015/12/when-should-you-use-a-container/). Not all applications benefit from using a DI Container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll end up with setup code that is coupled to the IOC container, but that's okay. The key is that the setup always occurs in the composition root of your application. Or in other words, the dependencies are specified at application startup before the classes are used. The classes themselves would operate with no awareness of the container or how the dependencies are being created.

Suppose these are your `Foo` classes and interfaces:

```
public interface IFoo { }

public interface IFooConfig { }

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    private readonly IFooConfig _config;

    public Foo(IFooConfig config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
}

public class FooConfigA : IFooConfig { }

public class FooConfigB : IFooConfig { }
```

Here's some container code. As you can see it gets complicated. If your dependencies are small and simple it may not be worth it.

Using Windsor as an example, your setup might look something like this. There's more than one way to do it, so I'll leave it to you decide whether it's simpler or preferable.

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IFooConfig, FooConfigA>().Named("FooConfigA"),
    Component.For<IFooConfig, FooConfigB>().Named("FooConfigB"),
    Component.For<IFoo, Foo>()
        .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<IFooConfig, FooConfigA>()).Named("FooA")
        .IsFallback(),
    Component.For<IFoo, Foo>()
        .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<IFooConfig, FooConfigB>()).Named("FooB"));
```

Now you have two registrations of `IFoo` with different names. Each one returns the same type of object (`Foo`) but each of those instances has a different implementation of `IFooConfiguration`.

Or if you're using instances of IFooConfig that come from `Settings.Default`, you would do this:

```
Component.For<IFoo, Foo>()
    .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("config", Default.Settings.FooConfigA))
    .Named("FooA")
    .IsFallback(),
Component.For<IFoo, Foo>()
    .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("config", Default.Settings.FooConfigB))
    .Named("FooB"),
```

Now for each class that depends on `IFoo` you'd have to either specify by name which version you get or you'll just get "A" because that's designated as the fallback.

As you can see, this quickly gets messy and complicated. Another approach, if possible, is to use an abstract factory to choose an implementation at runtime instead of having a separate registration for `IFoo` for each combination of dependencies. [Here's some more explanation and an example.](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/02/23/abstract-factory-pattern.html).

If you're using Windsor (and I'm sure other containers have similar behaviors) you could have a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<IFoo>` or `Foo[]`, and then Windsor will resolve *all* implementations and pass them to the constructor. You would add this to the container setup:

```
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ListResolver(container.Kernel, true));
```

Comment: If I were to look at this and compare it to the code at the top, I'd say I'm not really selling it. This stuff can be awesome and useful, but it's a tool for managing complexity. It doesn't solve the complexity, it just moves it somewhere else to keep it out of your hair when you don't need to deal with it. But if managing the complexity actually adds complexity then its value is questionable.

Comment: Note: There is only a single FooConfig class, and there are two instances of it. There are not separate FooConfigA and FooConfigB classes.

Also, importantly, Foo has other dependencies besides FooConfig, and Bar and Baz have other dependencies besides Foo.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I was following that correctly, so it's a good thing that this is all in generalities. You only need to specify the value for a dependency if there's not a registered type. So if your container already has components registered for the other types then it will resolve those automatically. That's a big part about what makes DI containers useful. There is some learning curve, but if you use it all the way down then it makes life easier.

Comment: Using Castle Windsor did end up increasing the number of lines of code in my setup, but it reads more clearly now, and it feels a lot easier to maintain.

My only real gripe with it is that when a type has multiple dependencies of the same type, you have to use a string to specify the argument name, meaning there would be a runtime error if someone changed the argument name without changing the dependency registration too. 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When using Simple Injector, the following registration is the equivalent of your current [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) approach:

```
var container = new Container();

container.Register<ISimpleDependency, SimpleDependency>();
container.Register<ISomeOtherDependency, SomeOtherDependency>();
container.Register<Bar>();
container.Register<Baz>();
container.Register<Qux>();

var fooAReg = Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration<IFoo>(
    () => new Foo(Settings.Default.FooConfigA, container.GetInstance<ISimpleDependency>()),
    container);

var fooBReg = Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration<IFoo>(
    () => new Foo(Settings.Default.FooConfigB, container.GetInstance<ISimpleDependency>()),
    container);

// The registrations for IFoo are conditional. We use fooA for Bar and fooB for Baz.
container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IFoo), fooAReg, 
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(Bar));
container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IFoo), fooBReg, 
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(Baz));

container.RegisterCollection<IFoo>(new[] { fooAReg, fooBReg });
```

Do note that this example does not use Auto-Wiring on all registrations; the `Foo` registrations are wired manually. This is because (as a safety measure) Simple Injector does not allow 'looking up' the call graph past its direct parent, because that could lead to incorrect results. This is why we can't inject `FooConfigB` into the `Foo` of `Bar` using Auto-Wiring.

**UPDATE**:

> What if I have two instances of Bar, one of which depends on the Foo with FooConfigA, and the other of which depends on the Foo with FooConfigB

```
var fooAProd = Lifestyle.Transient.CreateProducer<IFoo>(
    () => new Foo(Settings.Default.FooConfigA, container.GetInstance<ISimpleDependency>()),
    container);

var bar1Reg = Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration<Bar>(() => new Bar(
    fooAProd.GetInstance(),
    container.GetInstance<IOtherDep1>()));

var fooBProd = Lifestyle.Transient.CreateProducer<IFoo>(
    () => new Foo(Settings.Default.FooConfigB, container.GetInstance<ISimpleDependency>()),
    container);

var bar2Reg = Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration<Bar>(() => new Bar(
    fooBProd.GetInstance(),
    container.GetInstance<IOtherDep1>()));

// The registrations for IFoo are conditional. We use fooA for Bar and fooB for Baz.
container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IFoo), fooBProd.Registration, 
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(Baz));

container.RegisterCollection<IFoo>(new[] { fooAReg, fooBReg });
```

Comment: What if I have two instances of Bar, one of which depends on the Foo with FooConfigA, and the other of which depends on the Foo with FooConfigB? I was able to wire this up neatly using Castle Windsor, but I couldn't seem to figure out a way to make it work with SimpleInjector or any of the other lightweight containers.